# How I can change the style of a specific celldata in javafx?

Tags: javafx, tableview

Good Evening,
I would like to know, how i can change the background color to red of all below 18 year, is possible ?
I'm trying solve this since Monday. Could someone give me some website than explain better than oracle documentation ?
I see a lot of people, still using swing, Should I keep learn about javafx or start study swing ?
obs: sorry for my bad english.

Controller

```
package tableview;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

    public class LayoutController implements Initializable {

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            getPerson();
            columnFName.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getfName());
            columnLName.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getlName());
            columnAge.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().getAge());
            tableView.setItems(person);
        }    

        @FXML
        private AnchorPane layout;

        //TABLE
        @FXML
        private TableView<Person> tableView;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Person, String> columnLName;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Person, String> columnFName;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Person, Number> columnAge;
        //END

        ObservableList person = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList getPerson() {
            person.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 15));
            person.add(new Person("May", "Smith", 18));
            person.add(new Person("Sam", "Lucca", 21));
            person.add(new Person("Homer", "Simpson", 14));
            return person;
        }


    }
```

Person class

```
package tableview;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
    private SimpleStringProperty fName, lName;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty age;

    public Person() {
        this("", "", 0);
    }

    public Person(String fName, String lName, int age) {
        this.fName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a row factory on your table. You want to observe the `itemProperty` of the row. The best way to manage the background color is using an external CSS file and setting a CSS pseudoclass if the person represented by the row has age < 18. (You can put this code in your controller's `initialize()` method.)

```
    PseudoClass minorPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("minor");

    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Person> row =  new TableRow<>();
        row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (newPerson != null) {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, newPerson.getAge() < 18);
            } else {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, false);
            }
        });
        return row ;
    });
```

Then define an external style sheet with the appropriate style for the pseudoclass you created:

```
.table-row-cell:minor {
    -fx-control-inner-background: red ;
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: #cc0000 ;
}
```

Note that this assumes the age is fixed for each person in the table. If it has the possibility of changing while the person is displayed, you need to register and deregister listeners with the age property as the row content changes:

```
    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Person> row =  new TableRow<>();
        ChangeListener<Number> ageListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, newValue.intValue() < 18);
        };
        row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (oldPerson != null) {
                oldPerson.ageProperty().removeListener(ageListener);
            }
            if (newPerson != null) {
                newPerson.ageProperty().addListener(ageListener);
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, newPerson.getAge() < 18);
            } else {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, false);
            }
        });
        return row ;
    });
```

Here is a SSCCE. This doesn't use FXML, but obviously you can do the same thing, creating the `rowFactory` in the `initialize()` method in the controller.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightYoungPeopleTableExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty, 150);
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty, 150);
        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = column("Age", person -> person.ageProperty().asObject(), 50);

        PseudoClass minorPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("minor");

        tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Person> row =  new TableRow<>();
            ChangeListener<Number> ageListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, newValue.intValue() < 18);
            };
            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
                if (oldPerson != null) {
                    oldPerson.ageProperty().removeListener(ageListener);
                }
                if (newPerson != null) {
                    newPerson.ageProperty().addListener(ageListener);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, newPerson.getAge() < 18);
                } else {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(minorPseudoClass, false);
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(ageColumn);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("John", "Smith", 15),
                new Person("May", "Smith", 18),
                new Person("Sam", "Lucca", 21),
                new Person("Homer", "Simpson", 14)        
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(tableView), 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("highlight-young-people-table.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property, double width) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setPrefWidth(width);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setAge(age);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public final int getAge() {
            return this.ageProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setAge(final int age) {
            this.ageProperty().set(age);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

highlight-young-people-table.css

```
.table-row-cell:minor {
    -fx-control-inner-background: red ;
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: #cc0000 ;
}
```

Comment: I changed newPerson.getAge() < 18 to newPerson.getAge().intValue() < 18 and works fine, but is possible I change just the cell and not all row ?

Comment: Use a `cellFactory` on the `TableColumn` for that instead.